# Resolving NSNetService on server side

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnetservice

I have the problem in resolving `NSNetService`. i have successfully resolved `NSNetService` when `NSNetServiceBrowser` find that service.

```
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing{

    if (![self.services containsObject:aNetService]) {

        [aNetService setDelegate:self];
        [aNetService resolveWithTimeout:5.0];
    }
}
```

then this method is successfully called

```
-(void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender{

    NSArray *addresses = [ns addresses]; 
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSNetService dictionaryFromTXTRecordData:[sender TXTRecordData]];
    // Here both values are ok
}
```

but i want to resolve NSNetService to server side to get the IP address on which that service is published.

```
-(void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)ns{

    [ns setDelegate:self];
    [ns resolveWithTimeout:5.0];
}
```

but here this method is not calling.

```
-(void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender{
   
}
```

however i did this

```
-(void)netServiceDidPublish:(NSNetService *)ns
{
    NSArray *addresses = [ns addresses]; // this gives null

    // this also gives null
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSNetService dictionaryFromTXTRecordData:[sender TXTRecordData]];
}
```

but values are `null`.

please help me if it is possible. any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem the other day as well, and took me a while to figure it out.
For some reason, I needed to assign aNetService to a property.

```
# Declare a NSNetService property in the .h or further up .m file
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNetService *currentService;

# In the .m file.
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing{

    if (![self.services containsObject:aNetService]) {
        self.currentService = aNetService;
        [self.currentService setDelegate:self];
        [self.currentService resolveWithTimeout:5.0];
    }
}
```